# How to portably create a class at run-time in Common-Lisp CLOS

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clos, ccl

I need to create a class at run-time, possibly without resorting to eval. Knowing that the metaclass protocol is not fully standardized in Common-Lisp, after browsing through the [The Common Lisp Object System MetaObject Protocol](http://www.alu.org/mop/index.html), I tried the following code to create a class, instantiate it, and set a slot value of the instance to a number:

```
(defparameter *my-class*
  (make-instance 'standard-class
                 :name 'my-class
                 :direct-slots '((:name x :readers (get-x) :writers ((setf get-x))))))

(defparameter *my-instance* (make-instance *my-class*))

(setf (get-x *my-instance*) 42) ;; => 42
```

Unfortunately this code works correctly on SBCL, but not on CCL, where the class creation seems to work, but the instance creation `(make-instance *my-class*)` causes the following error:

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function:
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION INITIALIZE-INSTANCE #x30200002481F>
when called with arguments:
  (#<error printing CONS #x302001A9F6A3>
   [Condition of type CCL:NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-EXISTS]
```

I tried looking at [closer-mop](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop) package, that should hide the differences between the various implementations for the meta-object protocol, but I could not find any function or class useful to my scope.

So the question is: is there a portable way of creating a class and instantiating it at run time by using directly the metaclass level of CLOS?

Comment: With closer-mop, you could try [ensure-class](http://mop.lisp.se/dictionary.html#ensure-class), or [ensure-class-using-class](http://mop.lisp.se/dictionary.html#ensure-class-using-class).

Comment: CCL seems to work if you specify the direct superclasses too `:direct-superclasses (list (find-class 'standard-object))`

Comment: Thanks @jkiiski, the problem is that I should have specified the superclass. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @coredump, actually `ensure-class` does not work with my parameters, but works correctly if I add the direct-superclass `standard-object` (I was thinking it was a default, but maybe this is a default only for `defclass`).

Comment: Oh because B->C is indeed not preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCL seems to require that you manually specify the direct superclasses as well.

```
(defparameter *my-class*
  (make-instance 'standard-class
                 :name 'my-class
                 :direct-slots '((:name x :readers (get-x) :writers ((setf get-x))))
                 :direct-superclasses (list (find-class 'standard-object))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually one would use `ENSURE-CLASS` to create a class. The purpose of `ENSURE-CLASS` is to be the functional equivalent of `DEFCLASS`. Minus special implementation-specific things `DEFCLASS` does - for example to support features of the development environment.

You can use `MAKE-INSTANCE`, but for example it won't register the class under its name. It also would not call any additional `ENSURE-CLASS-USING-CLASS` methods.

Since the default for the metaclass is `standard-class`, CCL should also compute a default for the *direct superclasses*, which it does not - unfortunately.

I would hope that *closer-mop* fixes those incompatibilities, but I haven't checked.

In CCL:

```
? (ensure-class 'my-class
                :direct-slots '((:name x
                                 :readers (get-x)
                                 :writers ((setf get-x))))
                :direct-superclasses (list (find-class 'standard-object)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS MY-CLASS>
? (find-class 'my-class)
#<STANDARD-CLASS MY-CLASS>
? (let ((foo (make-instance 'my-class)))
    (setf (get-x foo) 10)
    (incf (get-x foo) 32)
    (get-x foo))
42
```

LispWorks actually does it correctly. The metaclass defaults to `standard-class` and the direct superclass is then `standard-object`.

```
CL-USER 25 > (clos:ensure-class 'foobar
                 :direct-slots '((:name x
                                  :readers (get-x)
                                  :writers ((setf get-x)))))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOOBAR 4020001713>

CL-USER 26 > (class-direct-superclasses *)
(#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT 40E018E313>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer!